# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ant, build, weblogic12c

I am trying to build my Java project with Ant.
But I am getting  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlException while executing the cleintgen Ant task.
I am not sure if I am missing any jar. I have added jars mentioned below in taskdef classpath attribute-

```
weblogic-classes.jar
wlthint3client.jar
wlfullclient.jar
xmlbeans-1.0.jar
```

Error at line -

```
<clientgenSRF wsdl="D:/POC/Code/WSDLs/Update_V3.wsdl"
                destFile="D:/POC/Code/SRF/clientstubs/newjar/createTroubleTicket_client.jar" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly missing in older version.
Upgrade xmlbeans-1.0.jar to xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar will be advantages.